# Newtonsoft Add a Keyed JObject in JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have tried numerous times and also tried to consult the documentation provided by Newtonsoft website but there doesn't seem to be any answer regarding my issue. I have also searched Google for no avail, wasted around 4 hours with no answer but just to continue without it.

My issue is that can't add a JObject into a JArray with a Key. I understand it seems rather simple task but whatever I tried ended up in an Exception being thrown out.

I am trying to write a simple file with the following layout:

```
{
    "items" : [
        "item 1" : {   }, 
        "item 2" : {   }, 
   ] 
} 
// the actual layout that I have is
{
    "items" : [
        {   }, 
        {   }, 
   ] 
}
```

I can successfully add the first `items` key for JArray through `jobj["items"] = jarray` but I cant seem to use the same technique with JArray. I need to add items in JArray through JArray.Add() and it doesn't let me provide a key. I'm actually lost on this. Can someone please explain as how can I achieve the above layout? Thank you.

Comment: As specified by https://json.org/, an **array** *is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [left bracket and ends with ]right bracket. Values are separated by ,comma.*  Thus `[ "item 1" : { }]` is not well-formed JSON and as such can't be created using Json.NET.  To confirm, upload your desired JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will get errors.

Comment: I am actually trying to create a json file. If this is not correct then what would be the correct layout?

Comment: *what would be the correct layout?* - the correct layout would be any layout generated by Json.NET and is well-formed according to https://json.org/.  Alternatively, if you are trying to interoperate with some pre-existing service or software, consult the documentation for the required layout.  But we have no way, *in general*, to understand your precise requirements from your question, assuming you want to generate well-formed JSON, since we don't know your required data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dbc mentioned, the format which you require is not valid. The nearest valid format you could achieve is as following.

```
{
   "items":
         {
            "item 1":{},
            "item 2":{}
         }
}
```

You could achieve it using a Data structure containing a Dictionary. For Example

```
var data = new DataStructure{ 
                                items = new Dictionary<string,Item>()
                                    {
                                    ["Item 1"] = new Item{},
                                    ["Item 2"] = new Item{}
                                    }};
```

Where DataStructure and Item is defined as

```
public class DataStructure
{
    public Dictionary<string,Item> items{get;set;}
}
public class Item
{

}
```

If you do not want to create concrete class, you can achieve the same using anonymous types

```
var data = new {items = new Dictionary<string,Item>()
                                {
                                ["Item 1"] = new Item{},
                                ["Item 2"] = new Item{}
                                }};
```

or, if you want to avoid creation of Item Class as well

```
var data = new {items = new Dictionary<string,object>()
                                {
                                ["Item 1"] = new {},
                                ["Item 2"] = new {}
                                }};
```

Output

```
{
  "items": {
    "Item 1": {},
    "Item 2": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That actually explains it and helped me optimize my code.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been suggested in the comment, my desired layout is not a right one. As it appears json needs an anonymous object within the array to hold a keyed object.

So the layout should be:

```
{
    "items" : [
        { 
            "item1" : {   } 
        }, 
....... 
   ] 
}
```